# Cpp switch statement won't output conditions set

Tags: c++, switch-statement, output

I'm running into a bit of an issue on a practice program from the cpp site.
The prompt is:

> Write a program that presents the user w/ a choice of your 5 favorite
>   beverages (Coke, Water, Sprite, ... , Whatever). Then allow the user
>   to choose a beverage by entering a number 1-5. Output which beverage
>   they chose.
>
> ★ If you program uses if statements instead of a switch statement,
>   modify it to use a switch statement. If instead your program uses a
>   switch statement, modify it to use if/else-if statements.

When I compile and run, there's no output after user input.

```
 #include <iostream>

//cola machine

main ()
{
    //intro and options
    std::cout << "Welcome. What will you have?";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1 - Coke";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2 - Pepsi";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3 - Mtn. Dew";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4 - Water";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5 - Cancel";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //choice
    int choice;

        std::cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
        {
            case '1':
                std::cout << "Coke";
                break;
            case '2':
                std::cout << "Pepsi";
                break;
            case '3':
                std::cout << "Mt. Dew";
                break;
            case '4':
                std::cout << "Water";
                break;
            case '5':
                std::cout << "void";
                break;

            default:
    std::cout << "enjoy your ";
    std::cout << choice;
    std::cout << "!";
        }
```

Any guidance would be amazing and thanks for your time.

Comment: Your `choice` is an `int` and you compare with character literals whose value is not the same as the digit they represent. `case '1':` is `case 49:` with ascii encoding.

Comment: `case '1'` should b just `case 1`: and same for the rest, '1' is type char, 1 is int. It compiles because '1' has a integer value, but it's not 1.

Comment: You could eliminate the `switch` statement and use an array of `std::string`:  `const std::string choices[] = {"Unknown", "Coke", "Pepsi", "Mtn. Dew", "Water", "Cancel"};`  You could then say:  `std::cout << choices[choice] << "\n";`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought about doing that tbh, but I am practicing strings and I just checked the prompt while writing this, it says:

"Write a program that presents the user w/ a choice of your 5 favorite beverages (Coke, Water, Sprite, ... , Whatever).
Then allow the user to choose a beverage by entering a number 1-5.
Output which beverage they chose.

★ If you program uses if statements instead of a switch statement, modify it to use a switch statement.
If instead your program uses a switch statement, modify it to use if/else-if statements."

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>

//cola machine

int main()
{
    //intro and options
    std::cout << "Welcome. What will you have?";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1 - Coke";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2 - Pepsi";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3 - Mtn. Dew";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4 - Water";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5 - Cancel";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //choice
    int choice;

    std::cin >> choice;

    std::cout << "Enjoy your ";

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "Coke";
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "Pepsi";
        break;
    case 3:
        std::cout << "Mt. Dew";
        break;
    case 4:
        std::cout << "Water";
        break;
    case 5:
        std::cout << "void";
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "NONE SELECTED";
    }

    std::cout << "!\n";

    system("PAUSE");
}
```